# Has a pitcher ever homered in an All-Star game?

Tags: baseball, trivia

With runs at a premium at times in All-Star games, and I know DH's are used in some games, has a pitcher ever homered in an All-Star game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Baseball Reference Play Index, 140 players have hit 182 home runs through the 2015 game, but no pitcher has ever hit a home run in the All-Star Game. Now that DH is used every year, this will likely never happen.

Some other ASG home run fun facts: Stan Musial has the most ASG home runs with 6. Ichiro hit an inside-the-park HR in 2007. Fred Lynn had the only grand slam in 1983. Naturally, Babe Ruth hit the first ASG home run in 1933.